# Setting a conditional for a random item selected from a list in Python

Tags: python, random

I'm working on a text-based Choose Your Own Adventure game in Python for an online class. The game has a list of random "villains" that you may encounter. The original project just has you going to the cave and finding a magical sword that you use to fight the villain. I wanted to set it so that the "weapon" would change according to whatever villian is selected randomly for the list. I listed the code I came up with (below), but it is not recognizing the choice of creature. Instead, it is returning the sword each time. What am I doing wrong?

```
creatures = ["wicked fairy", "gorgon", "troll", "dragon", "small child", "Karen", "ex-wife"]
weapons = ["Sword of Ogoroth", "Nintendo Switch", "social media", "alimony"]
creature = random.choice(creatures)
items = []


    if {creature} == "wicked fairy" or "gorgon" or "troll" or "dragon":
        # print messages here
        items.append("sword")
    elif {creature} == "small child":
        # print messages here
        items.append("Switch")
    elif {creature} == "Karen":
        # print messages here
        items.append("phone")
    else: 
        # print messages here
        items.append("money")
    

# edited to pare down the code so that only the relevant sections were listed


I tried using random choice and conditional statements.
```

Comment: Which programming language have you been using before Python?

Comment: The goal of stackoverflow is to create an archive of useful questions and answers. Editing your question to delete it and replace it with a “thank you” note is directly contrary to this site’s mission. Don’t do that! Please click on the question mark icon in the upper right corner and take the tour for a better understanding of what stackoverflow is all about.

Answer (score 1):

The core of the problem is that if you write:

```
if {creature} == "wicked fairy" or "gorgon" or "troll" or "dragon":
```

you have created a logical `or` of four items with only the first one being an actual comparison.

As a non-empty string evaluates in Python to True the 'condition' will always return True on "gorgon" as it is a non-empty string.

What you actually wanted to achieve was:

```
if creature in ["wicked fairy", "gorgon", "troll", "dragon"]:
```

And please don't forget to remove the curly braces in all the `elif` statements too as they are creating a Python set with one item in it what is not what you intend the code to do.

Comment: Also, the choice of items occur only inside the cave() function. The conditions inside the house_of_choice() function are never triggered unless cave() is called before.  I don't know if its intended, I would recommend to have a different function just to choose the weapon.

Comment: @Niko : it looks like the code was 1:1 taken from another programming language and translated to Python code, but ... not on each line the right way. The problem was probably that the code does not result in an error and the not translated lines were just overseen as needing correction.

Answer (score 0):

`if creature == "wicked fairy" or creature == "gorgon" or creature == "troll" or creature == "dragon":`

This works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).